# Using xlswrite in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I am working with three datasets in MATLAB, e.g.,

1. **Dates:**
   There are `D` dates that are chars each, but saved in a cell array.

   ```
   {'01-May-2019','02-May-2019','03-May-2019'....}
   ```
2. **Labels:**
   There are **100** labels that are strings each, but saved in a cell array.

   ```
   {'A','B','C',...}
   ```
3. **Values:**

   ```
   [0, 1, 2,...]
   ```

   This is one row of the `Values` matrix of size `D×100`.

I would like the following output in Excel:

```
date            labels     Values

01-May-2019       A           0
01-May-2019       B           1
01-May-2019       C           2
```

till the same date repeats itself **100** times. Then, the next date is added (+ repeated 100 times) onto the subsequent row along with the 100 labels in the second column and new values from 2nd row of `Values` matrix transposed in third column. This repeats until the date length `D` is reached.

For the first date, I used:

```
c_1 = {datestr(datenum(dates(1))*ones(100,1))}
c_2 = labels
c_3 = num2cell(Values(1,:)')
xlswrite('test.xls',[c_1, c_2, c_3])
```

but, unfortunately, this seemed to have put everything in one column, i.e., the date, then, labels, then, 1st row of values array. I need these to be in three columns.

Also, I think that the above needs to be in a `for` loop over each day that I am considering. I tried using the `table` function, but, didn't have much luck with it.

How to solve this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to build your columns and (optionally) add them to a table for exporting.

For example:

```
dates = {'01-May-2019','02-May-2019'};
labels = {'A','B', 'C'};
values = [0, 1, 2];

n_dates = numel(dates);
n_labels = numel(labels);

dates_repeated = reshape(repmat(dates, n_labels, 1), [], 1);
labels_repeated = reshape(repmat(labels, n_dates, 1).', [], 1);
values_repeated = reshape(repmat(values, n_dates, 1).', [], 1);

full_table = table(dates_repeated, labels_repeated, values_repeated);
```

Gives us the following table:

```
>> full_table

full_table =

  6×3 table

    dates_repeated    labels_repeated    values_repeated
    ______________    _______________    _______________

    '01-May-2019'           'A'                 0       
    '01-May-2019'           'B'                 1       
    '01-May-2019'           'C'                 2       
    '02-May-2019'           'A'                 0       
    '02-May-2019'           'B'                 1       
    '02-May-2019'           'C'                 2
```

Which should export to a spreadsheet with [`writetable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) as desired.

What we're doing with `repmat` and `reshape` is "stacking" the values and then converting them into a single column:

```
>> repmat(dates, n_labels, 1)

ans =

  3×2 cell array

    {'01-May-2019'}    {'02-May-2019'}
    {'01-May-2019'}    {'02-May-2019'}
    {'01-May-2019'}    {'02-May-2019'}
```

We transpose the labels and values so they get woven together (e.g `[0, 1, 0, 1]` vs `[0, 0, 1, 1]`), as `repmat` is column-major.

---

If you don't want the intermediate table, you can use [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to create a cell array from `values` so you can concatenate all 3 cell arrays together for [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) (or [`writematrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html), added in R2019a, which also deprecates `xlswrite`):

```
values_repeated = num2cell(reshape(repmat(values, n_dates, 1).', [], 1));
full_array = [dates_repeated, labels_repeated, values_repeated];
```

Comment: thank you for the help! since Values is a **(D x 100)** array, is it possible to amend your `values_repeated` line so that I can pull `Values(d, :)'` for each date `d` that's being considered? Ty

Comment: perhaps I can just write `values_repeated = reshape(Values',[],1);`? Basically, this would transpose all the rows of Values and combine them to get one single column vector? Ty

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. The latter is correct, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant soln!